# How to fetch the selected item from the mat-form-field in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material, dynamically-generated

I have created a simple application in angular2 where I have implemented **CanActivate Routeguard which routes to Admincomponent** when an Admin logs into the application.

I have also implemented **BehaviourSubject which defines the usertype** and if the user is **manager** then it hides the **AdminActivity** menu item from the **manager** user.

Now I want to generate URL's dynamically depending on the Institute selected by the Admin in AdminComponent.

Currently when admin selects the Institute from the dropdown and navigates the URL is
 **`http://localhost:4200/application/home`**

But I want to fetch the selected institute and dynamically generate the URL as **`http://localhost:4200/Arizona/application/home`** if the selected institute is **Arizona-ARZ**

Please access my sample stackblitz app [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/role-based-authentication-xnspcv?file=app%2Fadmin%2Fadmin.component.ts)

But I am unable to fetch the selected institute .Can anybody please help out how to fetch the selected item and use it for the generating the dynamic URL....?

Comment: Explain your question in general terms and point us to specific parts of the code. There is too much going on there for anyone to want to spend the time trying to figure it out, especially when there is no way for us to login and actually use the application.

Comment: Hi Did you resolved ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran... Hello sir .. please check this question if possible ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968040/unable-to-load-the-popup-in-angular-using-angular-material