# Unable to load the POPUP in angular using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a sample stackblitz demo implementing a simple angular material table in the popup component.

I have also taken an empty table where I am pushing the selected table rows from my first table to second empty table.

But the problem is here I am unable to run the stackblitz example, I tried out various ways to fix the issue but I am unable to find the solution.

Can anybody please help me out in resolving the issue **"popup undefined"**

And also when I am transferring table rows to the empty table , I am unable to select the checkbox in the second table to remove them back in the first table.

Please access my [sample demo here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-bqvby1?file=app%2Ftable.component.ts)

### Below shown is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your dialog module separately

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

instead of

```
import {MatDialogModule,...,...} from '@angular/material';
```

Working link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-y7sbxp?file=main.ts

Comment: Hello Sir ... please help me resolve this ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007272/transferring-row-data-from-between-two-tables-in-angular-using-angular-material

Answer (score 1):

You have not imported `OpenPopup` in your `main.ts`.

Make the following changes

**main.ts**:

`Import {TableComponent,OpenPopup} from './path'`

**tableComponent.component.ts**

`import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';`

Comment: thankyou for your feedback .. but still i am getting the error in my console as ..ERROR
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TableComponent -> MatDialog]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TableComponent -> MatDialog]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!

Comment: please check this link........https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-2xow5w?file=main.ts

Comment: Yeah i am looking into it